# Should a users table be in a different database than website content?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, authentication

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I did some searching and wasn't able to find an answer to my question.

I have my website content stored in a MySQL database (let's call it `content`) and I need to write a simple login system for my website. So, I need to create some sort of `users` table that holds usernames, passwords, permissions, etc., and what I'm wondering is whether I should just make this a new table in my `content` database, or if it would be more secure to have it stored in a new database? The downside to having it in a second database is that I will have to use two database connections instead of one.

Maybe this is a silly question, but I appreciate your input!

Comment: Personal preference, some will adamantly say yes, others will say there is no need. Personally, I would say no, there is no need

Comment: Short answer: no. It will be a massive headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a differnt db. That's more reserved for when you've got data that has completely DIFFERENT purposes, e.g. company A has a db and company B has a db.

Note that simply having two different databases does **NOT** require two different database connections to access. As long as the user ID you're logging into the DB with has proper access rights, you can do:

```
SELECT onedatabase.table.field, someotherdatabase.table.field
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving sensitive information to another database is a great [Defense In Depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_in_depth) strategy because it is limiting the impact of SQL Injection.  This works off the principle of isolation and planning on failure.  This is a common practice for protecting sensitive Medical or Finical information.  Often these separate databases will go a step further and store the information in an encrypted state.

SQL Injection under MySQL is very limited,  you cannot stack queries (e.g: `'; drop table ...`) and without MySQL's file privileges you cannot get a shell.  The only thing left that is useful is obtaining credentials using a `union select` or sub-select to access other tables or databases.  As long as you have separate user accounts,  and separate permissions an attacker will have to find SQL Injection in a query that is accessing the sensitive database,  which **reduces your attack surface**. Not be able to access sensitive information with SQL Injection makes this attack **much less useful**.

Also, [you should be using parametrized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Comment: This isn't defence in depth it's security by (a tiny wee bit of) obscurity.

Comment: @symcbean Oah that is not the impression I want to give,  perhaps you should read my updated post.  Secuirty though obscurity is an evil joke,  i would never suggest such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea. For security reason, it might be better not having users logging in at all. An idea is having a central admin account that you control, and then have the users send their content to you by mail. That way, you can be sure no one else will have access.

Answer (score -1):

As you say, you’d need to maintain more than one database connection if you were to do this. Although sand-boxing the databases is a nice thought, 99% of database-powered websites with user registrations will store the users with the content.

Comment: -1: you don't need more than one database connection if the databases are both implemented in the same mysql instance.